# 'session.gc-maxlifetime' is always at the default value

Tags: php, session

Im having problem extending the life of my session.

I tried

```
//start sessions
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60*60*22); //22h
echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
```

However, the echo shows "1440".. the default value.

Could my php.ini be protected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ini_set` is referring to an invalid ini setting, session.gc-maxlifetime, try changing to session.gc_maxlifetime (note the hyphen should be an underscore):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*22); //22h
echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
```

Answer (score 0):

max value for "session.gc_maxlifetime" is 65535. values bigger than this may cause  php session stops working.